# How to see if a wifi network is open or secured on windows 8

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I just installed windows 8.1. All is fine, but I don't know weather a network is secure or open.

It doesn't show any status besides the signal bar. I hover over it, right click but still not showing...

Or how can I make the pane for wifi networks look like the one in Windows 7.
Where it indicates the type of network - WAP, WPA etc and the status. Secured or open.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It’s really just like on Windows 7: Unsecured networks have the shield icon with an exclamation mark. It’s on the network you’re currently connected to:

[image]

Windows 10 also has this indicator.

Comment: only that ? And how can I see if the networks is WAP or WPA etc. ?

Comment: The Windows WiFi management GUI doesn’t offer that kind of information anymore. You can use the `netsh wlan show networks` command line command though.